# Node JS - Use Printer (Hardware)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, printing, hardware

I'm developing an application with Angular JS and Node JS where I need to see all available printers in the user's machine, let the user select one of them and print a receipt.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: This might help you https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer

Comment: Hey Agustin... es suficiente con mi respuesta o todavía estas atascado?

Comment: No lo he intentado aún, pero parece que funcionaría, en un rato te digo. gracias!

Comment: Hi! had you done this task? I need help I am also working on same task.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I did an application like that.. I did it using http://nwjs.io/ and the module in the comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/printer, here is a working code with this module printing raw in the default printer a file:

```
var printer = require('printer');
var fs = require('fs');

var info = fs.readFileSync('ticket.txt').toString();

function sendPrint() {
  printer.printDirect({
    data: info,
    type: 'RAW',
    success: function (jobID) {
      console.log("ID: " + jobID);
    },
    error: function (err) {
      console.log('printer module error: '+err);
      throw err;
    }
  });
}

sendPrint();
```

you can adapt it to use the getPrinters() method to enumerate all installed printers and then allow the user to select the desired one.