# Aurelia use printer to printout labels

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, printing, aurelia

I have a check in system with aurelia front and expressjs backend. I want to printout the label that gets created when a guest checks in. Is there a way to invoke printer from aurelia to printout the label? And in what format should the printout design be?

All needs to happen in the background. User just has the enter his/her data and press print and the lable is printed out.

Also how can i make sure that what im printing prints in landscape mode and fills the paper completly, currently it only fills a small corner of already small piece of paper in portrait mode.

Comment: Actually, your question is not related to Aurelia specific - but more to "how to print in Javascript" in general. From Aurelia, which runs in the browser, you can only use or trigger the native print dialog from the browser. From your node backend (Express.js) there are [more options available](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnode.js%5D+%5Bprinting%5D). Here is a [particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977475/node-js-use-printer-hardware) which might solve your problem.

Comment: @Juliën Jep i got it. Just had to modify the browser settings to use default printer silently. I also edited the question cause a neew problem relating to this one popped up.