# Print a file using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanted to print a file (pdf or txt file) using node.js i.e. from the server side. Whenever user clicks on some button at the front end, an API is called and a file should be sent to a printer to print from server side using the IP address(which is not known to the client) of the printer which is connected via LAN cable. I've tried this using IPP (internet printing protocol) and used IP address but could'nt print.

Edit:::
I've tried this code below:

[Screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WD6x2.jpg)

```
var ipp = require("ipp");
var fs = require("fs");
var printer = ipp.Printer("http://10.84.4.194/ipp/printer/canon");
var filename;
var filetype;

var filedata = "";
filedata = fs.readFileSync("./testfile.txt",'utf8');
filedata = Buffer.from(filedata, 'utf-8')
console.log("DATAA:  " , filedata)
var create_msg = {
  "operation-attributes-tag": {
    "requesting-user-name": "naveen.kumar"
  },
  "job-attributes-tag": {
    "media": "na_letter_8.5x11in"
  }
};

var Job_id = 0;

printer.execute("Create-Job", create_msg, function(err, res) {
  if(err) console.log("create error:",err)
    else{ console.log("create res:",res);
    job_id = res["job-id"];
  }
});

var send_msg = {
  "operation-attributes-tag": {
    "job-id": Job_id,
    "requesting-user-name": "naveen.kumar",
    "document-format": 'txt'
  },
  data: filedata
};
console.log("-------------",filedata,"90099090", filetype)
printer.execute("Send-Document", send_msg, function(err, res) {
  if(err) console.log("send err:",err);
  else console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Can you share us what you have tried ? Can you try this and check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977475/node-js-use-printer-hardware

Comment: What have you tried specifically? Can you write some code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node JS - Use Printer (Hardware)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977475/node-js-use-printer-hardware)

Comment: it seems you need to create a print api server using https://www.npmjs.com/package/printer

Comment: @Gaurav kandpal,  That is to check get the printers on client side. But my question is that printer is not at all related to client but I want to print to certain printer using its IP from server side.

Comment: Please post code as text, [not a screenshot / image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Here's an IPP specific wrapper. https://github.com/watson/ipp-printer