# How can i print txt files or string with Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, printing, electron

It's supposed to send print jobs to zebra printers. I need a way to see printers and be able to tell which printer to use. Sometimes one pc will be connected 2.
Best case is to print txt files
Couldn't find any good library.

Comment: Take a look at this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/31978682/2570277

Answer (score 1):

Zebra printer use ZPL command. You can construct the ZPL command yourself according to the ZPL II Programming Guide. Then you can send the message directly to the tcp port of your printer.

Here is the ZPL II Programming Guide:
https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/zpl/1994_46469lr1.pdf

Or you can use some 3rd-party library to construct the ZPL command.

This is one of the library to construct ZPL language:
https://github.com/ebpa/zpl-js

Otherwise if you use electron, you can also install the printer driver and use `window.print()` to invoke system print dialog.

Comment: I have made it work with the print window popping up after creating document and writing the ZPL to it. But I want to select a printer with the code and send it to print without a pop up window. Which should be possible with Electron and Node?

Comment: @Hodl I don't think you can select printer with code when you use system print window. If you have already had ZPL command, you just need to send to the printer via TCP, Serial or Bluetooth whatever your printer supported.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for the help. My best bet is to just use Zebra Browser Print to do the printing.